# UI design interface using ncurses

Tags: c, linux

i am working in **gtk** in **linux** and i am using **glade** for design the UI. so is there any ide in linux is available like glade for developing application using **ncurses**

thanks in advance.

Comment: GUI for ncurses? What a contradictory thing!

Comment: I suppose you mean ncurses? You write "ncruses" two times.

Comment: You da man! Take a look at the thing which was called "Turbo Vision". It might be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Google brought me to http://invisible-island.net/cdk/